# VBA: Looking for a value and copy and paste the value in a other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my VBA code.  The problem is that I have duplicate names - the main sheet "Manager" and the names of the sheets.

The code should go to every sheet and look for the value "Engagements ID" and then go one cell down. In every sheet the number of Engagements ID is different, so the code should search in every sheet (500 rows) - look for the value "Engagements ID" then copy and paste the cell what is one row below into my main sheet, which is called "Manager".

Thank you for help!! :) The value what I looking for is on every sheet in column B.

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check_Account()



Dim rng As Range
Dim xName As String
Dim i, j As Integer



For i = 3 To 6
xName = Cells(i, 1)
    If xName = "" Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName).Select
    Sheets(xName).Select

            For j = 1 To 500
                If rng.Cells(j, 2) = "Engagements ID" Then
                    rng.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Sheets("Manager").Select

                        If Range("B" & i) = "" Then
                            Range("B" & i).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
                            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                            :=False, Transpose:=False
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName).Select
                            Sheets(xName).Select
                            Cells(j, 2).Offset(1, 0).Select
                        Else
                            Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0).Select
                            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                            :=False, Transpose:=False
                            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName).Select
                            Sheets(xName).Select
                            Cells(j, 2).Offset(1, 0).Select
                        End If
                End If
            Next j
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You should watch:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Where is the error? And by "In every sheet the number of Engagements ID are different"; do you mean that the Engagement ID is different in every sheet or that there are multiple Engagement IDs in each sheet and you want to capture them all?

Comment: Is it go to each sheet named in the list of Managers in the Manager sheet column A, search range B1:B500 in each individual manager sheet for the cell containing the text "Engagements ID" then retrieve the value from one row below in the same column? Are the retrieved values then put in the Manager sheet next to each Manager's name? i.e. in column B.

Comment: Use Option Explicit at top to check variable declarations, fully qualify range references, don' t use .Select, store items in arrays or dictionary/collections and loop these. I would be tempted to store the manager names as keys in a dictionary and then loop these to select sheets, call a function that does a FIND text in col B and return value one row below, assign that function call result as the dictionary value. Loop the column next to the Managers names Manager sheet writing out the values of the dictionary. Should already be ordered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. I think you will like it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check_Account()
    ' 24 Nov 2017

    Dim TabName As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row
    Dim FirstFnd As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 3 To 6
        ' Tab names are found at Manager!A3:A6
        TabName = Worksheets("Manager").Cells(i, "A").Value
        If Len(TabName) = 0 Then Exit For

        On Error Resume Next
        With Worksheets(TabName)
            If Err Then
                MsgBox "Worksheet """ & TabName & """ doesn't exist.", _
                       vbInformation, "Missing Worksheet"
            Else
                Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng = Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(Rl, "B"))
                Set Fnd = Rng.Find("Engagements ID", _
                                   After:=Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count), _
                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, _
                                   MatchByte:=False)
                If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                    FirstFnd = Fnd.Row
                    Do
                        With Worksheets("Manager")
                            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            ' start writing in row 2
                            If Rl < 2 Then Rl = 2
                            .Cells(Rl, "B").Value = Fnd.Offset(1).Value
                        End With
                        Set Fnd = Rng.FindNext(Fnd)
                    Loop While Not Fnd Is Nothing And Fnd.Row <> FirstFnd
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and tested the code below, and I believe it does what you expected it to do:

```
   Sub foo()
    For i = 3 To 6
        xName = Sheets("Manager").Cells(i, 1).Value
        LastRow = Sheets(xName).Cells(Sheets(xName).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To LastRow
            If Sheets(xName).Cells(x, 2).Value = "Engagements ID" Then
                Sheets("Manager").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets(xName).Cells(x + 1, 2).Value
            End If
        Next x
    Next i
    End Sub
```

This does not have any validation against possible errors, if the manager sheet does not exist, then you will get an error... But at least the code is more concise and it points you in the right direction.